# 0 value in Django PositiveIntegerField?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, unsigned-integer

Can a field of type models.PositiveIntegerField contain a 0 value? I'm doing something like:

```
points = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Thanks,

I know I should try it myself, but I haven't a Django environment here.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, it can.  It is debatable whether it should--there is a longstanding bug report: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7609

Answer (score 9):

For those looking to exclude the 0, it's easy to write a [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/validators/#writing-validators) for that.

```
def validate_nonzero(value):
    if value == 0:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('Quantity %(value)s is not allowed'),
            params={'value': value},
        )
```

and then use it as such

```
fill_qty = models.PositiveIntegerField(
  default=0,
  validators=[MaxValueValidator(1000000), validate_nonzero]
)
```

Comment: what makes you say that?

Comment: May be my personal experience. And with this said on the docs, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run I can go to any part of the world and shout it out loud. :)

Comment: [`MinValueValidator`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.MinValueValidator) exists

Comment: @Boris MinValueValidator cannot be used to validate that the value is just `>0`.

Comment: @ruohola why not?

Comment: @Boris Ah, yeah. Actually it works okish for integer fields.

Comment: @ruohola why "okish"? It works for floats too, the source code is literally one line. https://github.com/django/django/blob/65b880b7268dd8fe97fde5af77bede46305eb499/django/core/validators.py#L392

Comment: @Boris No it does not work for floats, there is no smallest non-zero positive float.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.

The [model field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield) says so. For completeness, also quoted here:

> PositiveIntegerField
>
> ```
> class PositiveIntegerField([**options])
> ```
>
> Like an IntegerField, but must be either positive or zero (0). The value 0 is accepted for backward compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 4):

Well by the definition of a Positive Integer, it shouldn't accept a zero value, but django actually considers it in the sense of none-negative number which is zero inclusive. So, Yes it can accept a zero value

Comment: "The value 0 is accepted for backward compatibility reasons."

Answer (score 3):

Yes, **"PositiveIntegerField"** can contain **"0" value**.

For example, I defined **the model "Point"** as shown below:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Point(models.Model):
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Then, run this command below:

```
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
```

Now, I opened **"db.sqlite3"** then as you can see, **"CHECK("points" >= 0)"** is set to **"points" field** which means **"PositiveIntegerField"** can contain **"0" value**:

[image]