# Model validation. Don't want to repeat myself. Django

Tags: django, validation, model

I have a model `M` that has a field `num=models.IntegerField()`
I have a modelform called `F` for model `M`.
I want to ensure that num is never negative.

If I do validation in my form class, `F`, then I can do `clean_num()`:
if negative then throw `ValidationError('Num can never be negative')`.
This `ValidationError` will be automatically redisplayed to the user by
redirecting him to back to the form that he submitted and displaying
the 'Num can never be negative' message on top of the `num` field.
Thats all done automatically by django as soon as I throw the
`ValidationError` from the `clean_fieldname` method.

I would like to be able to do all that, but in the model class.

`F` is the `ModelForm` created from a model class `M`. `M` defines that
the field `num` can never be negative.

When I'm calling `is_valid()` on a form, I want the functions defined in the model
to check for validation for any `ModelForm` that references this model.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

See [Model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) (Django 1.2+ only).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [PositiveIntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield) for this particular problem.

If your validation depends only on field value, you can implement your own field type as described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/

Comment: Note that positive != non-negative.

Comment: In django, ``PositiveIntegerField`` can also contain zero values as it is implemented as ``unsigned int`` on database level. This was also discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248617/0-value-in-django-positiveintegerfield

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone who posted an answer. But i found exactly what i asked about so if you're interested:

You can define the proper validators just once for the model. All the forms using this model will have the ValidationError('cant use this name') be appended to their field_name.errors list.

Note, that they will be added to the field in the form for which the model field validator is running.

Anyway, check this out:

[Django: how to cleanup form fields and avoid code duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960795/django-how-to-cleanup-form-fields-and-avoid-code-duplication/2961987#2961987)